# Pattern Finding in terms of previous terms

Tags: pattern-recognition

Find the next terms of the pattern:

$$ 1,4,24,192,2120,31140,566202 \dots$$
Tell the pattern expression.
I have already tried Lagrange interpolation. But it is not accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can modify [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A002866) a bit to get yours.

Comment: I am finding it very difficult. Can you guide me how to modiy it

Comment: I can not find any pattern . Please help